# How to calculate % while keeping structure of the Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, csv, pandas-groupby, percentage

Could somebody kindly advise on how to use pandas to add and calculate the Winning percentage while keeping the structure of the dataframe?

Original dataframe:

```
Date    Name    Place
21-Mar  John    1
22-Apr  John    2
23-May  John    1
22-Apr  Alex    2
23-May  Alex    2
21-Mar  Jeff    1
22-Apr  Jeff    8
23-May  Jeff    5
22-Apr  Randy   4
23-May  Randy   5
23-Jun  Randy   1
24-Jul  Randy   1
```

Dataframe needed:

```
Date    Name    Place   Winning %
21-Mar  John    1   0.67
22-Apr  John    2   0.67
23-May  John    1   0.67
22-Apr  Alex    2   0.00
23-May  Alex    2   0.00
21-Mar  Jeff    1   0.33
22-Apr  Jeff    8   0.33
23-May  Jeff    3   0.33
22-Apr  Randy   3   0.50
23-May  Randy   2   0.50
23-Jun  Randy   1   0.50
24-Jul  Randy   1   0.50
```

Winning % = (total number of 1st place)/(number of time the swimming attended the race)

ex: John attended the race 3 times and gotten 1st place 2 times. Therefore, 2/3= 0.67

I've tried using crosstab, however, wasn't able to keep the original structure of the dataframe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compare values by [`Series.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) for `==` and count `mean` with [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) for return `Series` with same length like original `DataFrame`:

```
df['Winning %'] = df['Positions'].eq(1).groupby(df['Name']).transform('mean')

#alternative
#df['Winning %'] = (df.assign(new= df['Positions'].eq(1))
#                     .groupby('Name')['new']
#                     .transform('mean'))
print (df)
      Date   Name  Positions  Winning %
0   21-Mar   John          1   0.666667
1   22-Apr   John          2   0.666667
2   23-May   John          1   0.666667
3   22-Apr   Alex          2   0.000000
4   23-May   Alex          2   0.000000
5   21-Mar   Jeff          1   0.333333
6   22-Apr   Jeff          8   0.333333
7   23-May   Jeff          5   0.333333
8   22-Apr  Randy          4   0.500000
9   23-May  Randy          5   0.500000
10  23-Jun  Randy          1   0.500000
11  24-Jul  Randy          1   0.500000
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution using sum() of 1st places to divide the len of each group.

```
(
    df.set_index('Name')
    .assign(Winning_pct = df.groupby('Name').Place.apply(lambda x: x.eq(1).sum()/len(x)))
    .reset_index()
)
```

Comment: Yes I quite like your solution. I was working on my solution when you've posted yours.:-)

Comment: @ Allen, your solution works too and it give more options to the problem. Thank you!